# $2$-dimensional Noetherian integrally closed domains are Cohen-Macaulay

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian, integral-domain, cohen-macaulay

Any 1-dimensional Noetherian domain is Cohen-Macaulay (C-M).

> For the $2$-dimensional case, a condition of being integrally closed is necessary to be added for a Noetherian domain to be C-M, which I could not prove it.

Would anybody be so kind as to solve this?

> I also search for a non C-M $2$-dimensional Noetherian domain which is not integrally closed.

Thanks for any cooperation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Let $R$ be a noetherian integral domain of dimension $2$. If $R$ is integrally closed, then $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay.

From [Serre's normality criterion](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/031S) we have that $R$ satisfies $(R_1)$ and $(S_2)$.
$(R_1)$ gives that all the localizations of $R$ at height one primes are regular, and therefore Cohen-Macaulay. (In fact, we don't need to use $(R_1)$ in order to prove that $R_{\mathfrak p}$ is Cohen-Macaulay for prime ideals $\mathfrak p$ of height one.)
Now let $\mathfrak p$ be a height two prime ideal of $R$. From $(S_2)$ we get that $\operatorname{depth}R_{\mathfrak p}\ge2=\dim R_{\mathfrak p}$, so $R_{\mathfrak p}$ is Cohen-Macaulay.

$k[x^4,x^3y,xy^3,y^4]$ is $2$-dimensional, *not* Cohen-Macaulay and *not* integrally closed.

Comment: Let me mention that *integrally closed* is sufficient but not necessary for a $2$-dimensional integral domain to be Cohen-Macaulay.

Comment: In fact $(S_2)$ is enough to show that $R$ is CM (as you hint at in your comment). It is more interesting to give an example of a $2$-dimensional Cohen-Macaulay domain that is not integrally closed

Comment: @zcn Agree. (Actually I had in my mind the case of $R$ normal, but not necessarily an integral domain.) For an example, maybe $k[x^2,x^3,y]$ can work.

Comment: Yes, that looks like an excellent example

Comment: Just out of interest, let me give another (graded) example: $k[x^3, x^2y, y^3] \cong k[x,y,z]/(y^3 - x^2z)$ is also 2-dim CM but not normal. Checking non-normality is an interesting exercise (for a hint, one might try using Exercise 4.22 in Eisenbud)

Comment: I have a hunch. I guess that perhaps one could turn for the local case and, assuming $m$ to be the only maximal ideal of $R$,  (perhaps)  prove that $m^{-1}=R$, since this is equivalent to $grade(m)≥2=ht(m)$, so equality would hold. But, I do not know (1) is the problem is valid for the local case, (2) if this is so, is $m^{-1}=R$, and (iii) how could we return to the general non-local case?

Comment: @karparvar Yes, one can use your approach for a direct proof without using explicitly the Serre's normality criterion. We can easily reduce the problem to the local $2$-dimensional case. Now take $t\in K$ ($K$ denotes the field of fractions of $R$) such that $t\mathfrak m\subseteq R$. Then $t\mathfrak m\subseteq\mathfrak m$ (if $t\mathfrak m=R$ it follows that $\mathfrak m$ is principal, contradiction with $\dim R=2$). From $t\mathfrak m\subseteq\mathfrak m$ we get a *monic* polynomial with coefficients in $R$ having $t$ as a root, so $t\in R$.

Comment: That is Ok!  Thank you very much. Now, one of my issues is why the local case is  sufficient?

Comment: Is it because $R$ being C-M is equivalent to $R_{M}$ is so for any maximal ideal $M$?

Comment: Thanking to all persons contributing to this problem, I demand an explicit example of a two dimensional C-M domain. Grateful!