# $R/\operatorname{rad}(0)$ is Cohen-Macaulay

Tags: commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

> If $(R,m)$ is a local Noetherian ring, is it true that $\bar R=R/\operatorname{rad} (0)$ is a Cohen-Macaulay ring?

I think that we should take a maximal chain of prime ideals of length $d$ under $\bar m$ and try to find an $\bar R$-sequence of length $d$ in $\bar m$ to get grade of $\bar m$ at least height of $\bar m$.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this would be true, then any reduced local ring would be Cohen-Macaulay. But this is clearly false, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825920/2-dimensional-noetherian-integrally-closed-domains-are-cohen-macaulay) for example.

That the ring is local is not relevant, since Cohen-Macaulay is a local property anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But why the ring in the answer is local?

Comment: You can just localize it. This does not change the fact, that its a domain, which is not Cohen-Macaulay.

Comment: It remains to me to ask that why the ring in the answer is not C-M?

Comment: $x^4,y^4$ is a system of parameters, since its radical is the maximal ideal. But $x^4,y^4$ is not a regular sequence, since we have $y^4(x^3y)^2=x^4(xy^3)^2$ and this shows that $y^4$ is a zero-divisor after dividing out $x^4$.

In a CM-ring, any system of parameters is a regular sequence.